# React-Native: LocalStorage deleted when app reloaded when using domStorageEnabled

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, webview, react-native

I have at the moment a small log in system which stores with AsyncStorage the session token and the refresh token. After you are logged in you are sent to the page Dashboard where I'm getting from the AsyncStorage the session and refresh token and passing them to a link in a WebView. The only way how the webView works for me is passing the domStorageEnabled={true} but this is deleting all storage when app is closed so the user needs again to log in. Do you know a way how to manage this problem?

```
render() {
    if (this.state.access_token = null) {
        return (
            <SplashScreen visible={true}/>
        );
    }
    else {
        let source = {uri: `myurl/auth/login?access_token=${this.state.access_token}&refresh_token=${this.state.refresh_token}`};
        return (
            <WebView
                source={source}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: you can inject some javascript. If you have the response from Asyncstorage you can update the javascript injection, which should lead you to your site

Comment: I'm not getting in my head a logic how to ...

Comment: ah actually it is much simpler. just add "source" as a state variable. and when you get the value from Asyncstorage you can update this.state.source -> this should trigger a rerender and update your webview